# Xvfb missing title bar

Tags: xvfb

I am trying execute desktop programs using Xvfb but the titlebar are missing.

Example:

```
# start desktop environment
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x16 &

# access to desktop environment
x11vnc -display :1 -localhost &
vncviewer :0 &

# run wine
DISPLAY=:1 wine winecfg
```

Screenshot:
[image: Missing titlebar in Xvfb]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Titlebars on windows are the responsibility of the window manager. Since you didn't run one, you're getting only the interface elements actually provided by the application.

I don't know what the fashionable window manager is these days... if you're very traditional, this will work:

```
twm -display :1 &
```

Comment: Thanks found a a similar solution with `DISPLAY=:1 openbox &`. If your solution works I will accept it as valid answer.